# How can we understand the accounting entries in oracle applications or Oracle EBS?

Tags: oracle-apps, oracleapplications, oracle-ebs

I need to understand the accounting entries that are created in Oracle ebs. For example, when we talk about a standard P2P cycle, there are certain accounting entries created right from the moment a purchase order is created, approved and received. 
I have basic knowledge of debit and credit entries. But when it comes to making debit and credit entries in Oracle apps, when I look at the accounts being used, I can not apply the basic dr cr entry rules to the accounts. 
Please advise on this. Kindly also suggest some resources from where I can obtain this information.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a simple answer as the DR and CR entries are all driven by the accounting setup.  To use your example, when a PO is created, very little accounting is done.  It isn't until the line is received and Create Accounting is run that debits and credits are really applied based on how the accounting rules are set.  If you were to open a PO, click "All Distributions", select a line and then click Tools > View Accounting Events, you'll see the detailed debits and credits that the accounting setup has created.

I'm not sure what your role is (developer, analyst, accountant etc.) or your experience level, but I would suggest you familiarize yourself with the accounting setup of your organization to be able to truly understand it.  My suggestion is to get a Financial Super User responsibility in your development environment and ask one of your Financial Analysts to show you the basics of your account setup.

If you really want a deep dive, login to your My Oracle Support account and start looking at the documentation (Doc 1597048.1).  The user guides are exhaustive but very helpful when you get the right one.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have no background in financial accounting, however I have been working in Oracle EBS for the last four years as a functional consultant in supply chain. I want to understand the accounting stuff as well. When you say accounting setup, can you please give me an example in layman terms ? I have access to financial super user responsibility in dev environment and I am willing to explore and learn. Thank you once again for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The debit and credit depends on the accounting rule setup.

In simple terms:

Inv Validated:___Dr-------Cr

Inv Exp...............100

Liability...........................100

Inv Paid:________Dr-------Cr

Liability........100

Cash................................100

There can be several steps in between depending on the Accounting rules, like Encumbrance accounting.